# Flutter Stripe payment in iOS not working, message: "Payment not completed"

Tags: ios, flutter, stripe-payments

The issue is when I try to do payment with real device on iOS:

error:
StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: Payment not completed, message: Payment not completed, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))

```
    await Stripe.instance.confirmPlatformPayPaymentIntent(
      clientSecret: event.clientSecret,
      confirmParams: PlatformPayConfirmParams.applePay(
        applePay: ApplePayParams(
          merchantCountryCode: "FR",
          currencyCode: "EUR",
          cartItems: [
            ApplePayCartSummaryItem.immediate(
              label: event.title,
              amount: "${event.amount}",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

the result is:
LOG ANALYTICS: ["pay_var": "legacy", "ocr_type": "none", "install": "C", "event": "mc_complete_init_applepay", "product_usage": ["PaymentSheet"], "app_name": "flutter_quiz", "analytics_ua": "analytics.stripeios-1.0", "bindings_version": "23.3.4", "locale": "en_US", "device_type": "iPhone10,3", "additional_info": [], "mpe_config": ["save_payment_method_opt_in_behavior": "automatic", "allows_delayed_payment_methods": false, "customer": false, "apple_pay_config": true, "style": 2, "return_url": false, "appearance": ["primary_button": false, "shadow": false, "colors": false, "usage": false, "border_width": false, "corner_radius": false, "font": false], "default_billing_details": false], "session_id": "018df625-0281-47f2-a6ed-a43f4ea831a8", "app_version": "1.0.0", "plugin_type": "flutter", "apple_pay_enabled": 0, "os_version": "16.3.1", "publishable_key": "pk_test_==============="]
flutter: Stripe error is: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: Payment not completed, message: Payment not completed, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))

An important point:
On the simulator is working without problem.

Comment: You should reach out to the `flutter_stripe` maintainers about this, potentially filing an issue with clear reproduction to be investigated:
https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues